# How can I avoid dust on my eyecup rubber?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, cleaning, viewfinder, dust

The [Nikon DK-21 rubber eyecup](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/407314-REG/Nikon_25335.html) just collects so much dust and I have to wash it regularly to keep it clean.

Any suggestions on how to keep this clean in the camera bag and when handling the camera? or any replacement for the DK-21 that doesn't collect so much dust?

PS. *I'm looking for some kind of anti-static solution, maybe a different kind of eyecup or an eye-safe anti-static spray.*

Comment: What concern do you have about your eyes? I don't get that. Dust is throughout the air all the time, and you open your eyes I am assuming :P If your eyes are more sensitive then some of us, maybe wear glasses or goggles of some sort?

Comment: I'm not sure about other eyecups and materials, but this rubber is just like a dust magnet! it's not normal lol maybe it's the winter clothes that makes it to attract dusts... I'm just looking for a solution, maybe an eye-safe anti-static spray?...

Comment: @dpollitt by 'eye safe' I'm sure he means any sprays can't be irritants,  since the eyecup is pressed against the sensitive skin around the eye.

Comment: @Tom Brossman, dpollitt is referring to a part of question that I decided to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try [one of these](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/37326-REG/Nikon_2380_DK_5_Eyepiece_Shield_Replacement.html) eyepiece covers. These are usually used for preventing light from entering the eyepiece and biasing meter settings for long exposures, but it might keep dust off as well.

Comment: Maybe a fix for the dust but not for the eyecup :) I don't want to cover it!

Comment: Hmmm. Tricky. Well, I'm not sure the problem is static... When most people look through the finder they tend to press their face onto the back of the camera. Oils can build up on the rubber eyepiece and make it somewhat sticky. This can also happen to the finder window itself because of contact with eyelashes when you blink. This buildup can act to retain dust that happens to contact those areas of the finder. The only thing I can think of besides a cover is to have two eyepieces (spare is only ~$12) and swap when needed. Clean the dirty spare with 409 or other grease cutter. Rinse/dry well.

Comment: I usually wash the eyecup with water and normal soap, I don't think the problem is oil, although having multiple eyecups seems to be a good idea, but I thought more experienced photographers may know a better solution, like a different kind of rubber/plastic eyecup.

Comment: I accepted your comment as the answer, having multiple eyecups seems to be the best solution.